# RadComboBox DropDownList is dittached from its place

Tags: radgrid, radcombobox

There is a `RadGrid` which contains `RadcomboBox` along with `button` next to it.
When user key-in something and click on button, data bind in `RadComboBox` related to key-in text and display in `DropdownList`.

but this `DropdownList` appear far below from `RadcomboBox`, which disturbs the look & feel of the page. Please refer the attached issue snapshot.
[image]

I tried to set `ExpandDirection="Down"` property but did not worked.
Also I tried to set `EnableScreenBoundaryDetection="false"`, this sticks the 
Dropdownlist at the bottom of page, so when I scroll the page , DropDown always stick at bottom & it also scrolls with the page.

Also, I set the `HighlightTemplatedItems="true"` but it is not working at all.

**EDIT:** 
HTML code:

```
 <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage6" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" Width="100%">
    <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView5" runat="server" Width="100%">                                                                             
    <%--<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel5" runat="server">--%>
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RGGSTAcCode" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
           ShowFooter="True" GroupingEnabled="False" ShowStatusBar="true"         
           AllowAutomaticInserts="False" AllowAutomaticUpdates="False" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true"
           OnNeedDataSource= "rggstAcCode_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="rggstAcCode_ItemDataBound"                    
           OnInsertCommand="rggstAcCode_InsertCommand" OnDeleteCommand="rggstAcCode_DeleteCommand"
           OnUpdateCommand="rggstAcCode_UpdateCommand" EnableEmbeddedSkins="true" Skin="Outlook">

        <mastertableview commanditemdisplay="Top" autogeneratecolumns="false" datakeynames="AccountCodeID" 
           insertitempageindexaction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true">

           <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="New" />
             <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="imagebutton1" ButtonType="ImageButton"></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>

                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Code">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") + " - " + Eval("AccountDescription")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                     <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlAccountCode" runat="server" Height="200" Width="260" DropDownWidth="310"       
                       EnableLoadOnDemand="True" OnItemsRequested="ddlAccountCode_ItemsRequested" EnableItemCaching="true"  
                       ShowMoreResultsBox="True" EnableVirtualScrolling="true" AllowCustomText="true" MarkFirstMatch="true"
                       Filter="Contains" HighlightTemplatedItems="true" CausesValidation="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                       DataTextField="AccountDescription" DataValueField="AccountCodeID"
                       ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick="false"
                       OnClientDropDownOpening="OnClientDropDownOpening" OnClientItemsRequested="OnClientItemsRequested">                                    
                     </telerik:RadComboBox>              

                     <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" OnClientClick="ButtonClicked()" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />&nbsp; 
                  </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                //Other columns
             </Columns>

             <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
             </EditFormSettings>
             <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
        </mastertableview>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    <%--</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>--%>
    </telerik:RadPageView>                                                                         
    </telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

C# code:

```
protected void ddlAccountCode_ItemsRequested(object sender, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Text"] = e.Text;
        Session["NumberOfItems"] = e.NumberOfItems;

        RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)sender;
        combo.ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick = false;
        combo.Items.Clear();
        combo.HighlightTemplatedItems = true;
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridEditableItem editedItem = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as GridEditableItem;

            RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)editedItem.FindControl("ddlAccountCode");
            //clear the previous items on every new search
            combo.Items.Clear();
            combo.OpenDropDownOnLoad = true; // opens dropdown of RadComboBox on button click
            combo.HighlightTemplatedItems = true; // to highlight the searched text

            //Code related to search in RadComboBox
            combo.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Please let me know how to resolve the 2 issues. Please reply.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `RadAjaxPanel` and used the asp.net `UpdatePanel` and the issue resolved as of now as the page will not post back on button click and above behavior will never happen. But I dont know why it is creating issue when I do not put `RadGrid` in `RadAjaxPanel` or `UpdatePanel`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can't replicate your problem in my environment....

Here is my code using

.aspx

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RGGSTAcCode" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
     ShowFooter="True" GroupingEnabled="False" ShowStatusBar="true"         
     AllowAutomaticInserts="False" AllowAutomaticUpdates="False" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true"
     OnNeedDataSource="rggstAcCode_NeedDataSource">
        <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
         InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true">
            <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="New" />
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="imagebutton1" ButtonType="ImageButton"></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Code">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") + " - " + Eval("AccountDescription")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlAccountCode" runat="server" Height="200" Width="260" DropDownWidth="310"       
                         EnableItemCaching="true" ShowMoreResultsBox="True" EnableVirtualScrolling="true" AllowCustomText="true" 
                         MarkFirstMatch="true" Filter="Contains" HighlightTemplatedItems="true" CausesValidation="true" 
                         AppendDataBoundItems="true" ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick="false" OnItemsRequested="ddlAccountCode_ItemsRequested">
                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />&nbsp; 
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>            
            </Columns>
        <EditFormSettings>
            <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
        </EditFormSettings>
        <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Variable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("AccountCode");
        dt.Columns.Add("AccountDescription");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) dt.Rows.Add("AccountCode" + i, "AccountDescription" + i);

        ViewState["data"] = dt;

        // Bind
        RGGSTAcCode.DataSource = dt;
        RGGSTAcCode.DataBind();

        // Dispose
        dt.Dispose();
    }
}

protected void rggstAcCode_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    RGGSTAcCode.DataSource = ViewState["data"] as DataTable;
}

protected void ddlAccountCode_ItemsRequested(object sender, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    Session["Text"] = e.Text;
    Session["NumberOfItems"] = e.NumberOfItems;

    RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)sender;
    combo.ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick = false;
    combo.Items.Clear();
    combo.HighlightTemplatedItems = true;
}

protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridEditableItem editedItem = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as GridEditableItem;

        RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)editedItem.FindControl("ddlAccountCode");
        //clear the previous items on every new search
        combo.Items.Clear();
        combo.OpenDropDownOnLoad = true; // opens dropdown of RadComboBox on button click
        combo.HighlightTemplatedItems = true; // to highlight the searched text

        //Code related to search in RadComboBox
        combo.DataSource = ViewState["data"] as DataTable;
        combo.DataTextField = "AccountCode";
        combo.DataValueField = "AccountCode";
        combo.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Result as below
[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please review my posted question again, I have no where mentioned that `DropDowList` is getting close while scroll. The code I wrote for above `RadComboBox` is an asp.net c# code not sharepoint code, but yes I am using sharepoint in my application. My issue is when I do not put `RadGrid` inside `RadAjaxPanel`, then the `RadComboBox` `DropDownList` appear far away from it. Please reply

Comment: Do you even check your .rcbList class

Comment: yes I do checked it. Code wise, all seems to be fine as I am using same code in another page but there `RadGrid` is inside `RadAjaxPanel` and its working fine without any issue.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the code... Without code no people can really help you...

Comment: But my side when I run the web page without putting RadGrid in RadAjaxPanel, DropDownList of RadComboBox appears like above snapshot. Any idea why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90288/discussion-between-user3196511-and-nicholas).